# Creating a clean bevelled edge around an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, inkscape, image-editing

I want to be able to create this clean bevelled edge on the border of a picture in GIMP, Photoshop or Inkscape. This is an example of what I want to recreate:

[image]

Comment: This is a very basic layer effect in Photoshop, please take a look around the internet before asking such basic questions here.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, edit the Layer Style and use **Bevel & Emboss**:

- Style: Inner Bevel
- Technique: Chisel Hard

[image: Screenshot]